# Duda sobre strcopy

Tags: c, string

Me gustaría saber cuál es la **función real** de **strcopy** de la librería **string.h** y que hace este método de C , creo que lo que hay en una conjuntos de carácteres se copia en un puntero de otro conjunto de carácteres. Pero me gustaría saber que hace exactamente y si copia todas las direcciones de memoria hasta \0 , o todas sin tener en cuenta \0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El strcopy copia un string en otro puntero. Te copia la cadena completa y la cadena termina con el \0 incluido. Sobre el puntero destino comienza a poner el string del origen, tienes el contenido por duplicado apuntado cada uno por su puntero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char src[40];
   char dest[100];

   memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));
   strcpy(src, "Hola buenos días");
   strcpy(dest, src);

   printf("String final : %s\n", dest);

   return(0);
}
```

Esto imprime "String final : Hola buenos días"